# JavaScript: Pushing nested object key value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, push, key-value, spread-syntax

I'm fetching JSON data from Firebase and wanting to transform the data in a different way. My question is how do I push a nested object key value pair into a single object?

Here is my code...

```
const postData = [];

for (const key in data) {
  postData.push({
   id: key,
   postComments: data[key].hasOwnProperty('comments')
     ? {
         id: Object.keys(data[key].comments),
         ...Object.values(data[key].comments),
       }
     : [],
   ...data[key]
  });
};

console.log(postData);
```

I'm currently getting:

```
{id: "-M_Spc3mBWVkUWKAAk_u", likes: 0, day: 22, month: 3,
     comments: {
       -M_McCXxZuoF60tmcKCV: {likes: 12, day: 23, month: 3}
       -M_Mc93EsXFxA_OS7g6Q: {likes: 234, day: 22, month: 3}
     }
     postComments: [
       0: {likes: 12, day: 23, month: 3}
       1: {likes: 234, day: 22, month: 3}
       id: ['-M_McCXxZuoF60tmcKCV', '-M_Mc93EsXFxA_OS7g6Q']
     ]
 }
```

I want the data to output:

```
{id: "-M_Spc3mBWVkUWKAAk_u", likes: 0, day: 22, month: 3,
     comments: {
       -M_McCXxZuoF60tmcKCV: {likes: 12, day: 23, month: 3}
       -M_Mc93EsXFxA_OS7g6Q: {likes: 234, day: 22, month: 3}
     }
     postComments: [
       0: {id: "-M_McCXxZuoF60tmcKCV", likes: 12, day: 23, month: 3}
       1: {id: "-M_Mc93EsXFxA_OS7g6Q", likes: 234, day: 22, month: 3}
     ]
 }
```

I've struggled on this for a couple days. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How your json input data looks like?

Comment: Can you please post the original data object? It will make it easier to figure out how to transform the data.

Comment: In your  " I'm currently getting "  `postComments` cannot have an id property as it is an array. Can you please post the original data object?

Comment: Updated with comments obj. Sorry about missing that data point.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ulou for getting me thinking with your .map answer. I don't how I didn't think of that. I must be burned out lol. Here is the answer I was looking for.

```
  for (const key in data) {
    postData.push({
      id: key,
      postComments: data[key].hasOwnProperty("comments")
        ? Object.entries(data[key].comments).map((k) => ({
            id: k[0],
            ...k[1],
          }))
        : [],
      ...data[key],
    });
  }
```